# Aggregate Data based on a column value in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, report

I am editing this question completely, as the desired result is changed a bit now. Also, I do agree, this question was not properly put forward to you guys.

I have a spreadsheet namely Main Spreadsheet, which contains the activities/rows as listed. I want to notify the assignees about the activities they will be performing and the dates as well.
I am able to write an email sending macro, but the problem is to reach that stage!
How can we sort, and then ensure that the recipient is only 1 person who is the assignee, and his name is not in the "TO" field more than once. (Applying the `for` loop creates the pain!)

Main Spreadsheet:

```
Date    Assignee    Activity
08/01   Player X    Activity 1
08/01   Player Y    Activity 1
08/02   Player X    Activity 2
08/02   Player Y    Activity 2
08/02   Player Z    Activity 1
```

Report to be computed:

```
Assignee    Activity List
Player X    Activity 1
Player X    Activity 2
```

Comment: No need for VBA on this. Try `SUMIF` formula and hide your original data sheet. If you need it really hidden you can protect the workbook with a password so users can't unhide, or at very least you can use VBA against the sheets `Visible` property, by setting it to `xlVeryHidden`.

Comment: If you already have code, please post it - it's easier to adapt it than to write it from scratch ;)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a For loop and assign the activities (and/or any other relevant info) to person-specific arrays. Then use the array to populate the email.

This isn't very elegant, but it runs on the example data you provided. You could either use the array data (and iterate through the items) or use the comma separated string for a player to populate an email.

```
Public Sub ReportToPeople()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim arrPlayerX()
    Dim arrPlayerY()
    Dim arrPlayerZ()
    Dim strPlayerX As String
    Dim strPlayerY As String
    Dim strPlayerZ As String

    ReDim arrPlayerX(1 To 1)
    ReDim arrPlayerY(1 To 1)
    ReDim arrPlayerZ(1 To 1)

    ' No clue how large your dataset is...
    For i = 2 To 100
        If Cells(i, 1).Value = vbNullString Then Exit For
        Select Case Cells(i, 2).Value
            Case "Player X"
                Call fArrIncrementAndAdd(arrPlayerX, Cells(i, 3).Value, strPlayerX)
            Case "Player Y"
                Call fArrIncrementAndAdd(arrPlayerY, Cells(i, 3).Value, strPlayerY)
            Case "Player Z"
                Call fArrIncrementAndAdd(arrPlayerZ, Cells(i, 3).Value, strPlayerZ)
        End Select
    Next i
    Call MsgBox(strPlayerX) 'or use Debug.Print strPlayerX
End Sub


Public Function fArrIncrementAndAdd(ByRef arrTheArray, ByVal strValueToAdd, ByRef strWholeString)
    Dim c As Integer

    c = UBound(arrTheArray)
    If arrTheArray(c) <> vbNullString Then ReDim Preserve arrTheArray(1 To (c + 1))
    arrTheArray(c) = strValueToAdd
    strWholeString = strWholeString & "," & strValueToAdd
    If UBound(arrTheArray) = 1 Then strWholeString = Replace(strWholeString, ",", "") ' removes leading comma on first item

End Function
```